# checking @react-native-community/netinfo network connection in react native isconnected is not working

Tags: typescript, react-native, android-emulator, react-native-community-netinfo

I have a problem with my application. I am actually doing a network connection check in the application before I can make an API call. I'm not connected to the internet but I'm getting a contrary response from the library #@react-native-community/netinfo

Can anyone help me?

[android-emulator, terminal, code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Ewy.png)

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing it on emulator then it does not work on emulator. Suppose you got disconnected from the internet and connect back but the emulator will stay in the disconnected mode until and unless you restart your app.

Make sure to test it on real device.